# CLIPS and primary defmessage-handlers

Tags: clips, expert-system

i've a big problem with CLIPS and classes. 
I've developed a small security-assessment in CLIPS, however when asking questions if the user want a better explanation he could click a button and he'll receive the explanation.
To do so, my system have a class like this:

```
(defclass QUESTION (is-a USER)
(role concrete)
(pattern-match reactive)
(slot id (type STRING))
(slot description (type STRING) (create-accessor read)))
```

and a set of instances like this:

```
(definstances EXPLANATION
(E1 of QUESTION (id "GQ01")(description "Choose YES if you don't know ... ")))
```

to retrieve descriptions the system use this operation::

```
(send (find-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (str-compare ?f:id ?id-question)) get-description)
```

the problem is that when executing it i receive this message:

```
[MSGFUN1] No applicable primary message-handlers found for get-description.
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of deffunction explain-question.
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of deffunction yes-or-no-p.
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of defrule ask-for-component-needed.
```

how can i solve? I want that if **?id-question** is equal of **id of an instance** of the instance-set the system will print the description associated with the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Functions find-instance and find-all-instances return a multifield value if an instance(s) is found, otherwise FALSE is returned, so you need to extract the instance value from the multifield (using nth$) and pass that to send rather than the multifield. Also in CLIPS the boolean false value is the symbol FALSE and boolean operations treat any non-FALSE value as true. Since the return value of str-compare is an integer, you need to explicitly compare the value to 0 using = or != if you're going to use it for the query in your find-instance call. There's not much point in using str-compare unless you're trying to lexically order strings, so in this case just use eq.

I'd also suggest using do-for-instance rather than find-instance. In the case where no matching QUESTION instance is found, you need to explicitly test that nth$/find-instance returned a valid value otherwise the call to send will cause an error.

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defclass QUESTION (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot id (type STRING))
   (slot description (type STRING)))
CLIPS>    
(definstances EXPLANATION
   (E1 of QUESTION (id "GQ01")
                   (description "Choose YES if you don't know ... ")))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (bind ?id-question "GQ01")
"GQ01"
CLIPS> (send (find-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (str-compare ?f:id ?id-question)) get-description)
[MSGFUN1] No applicable primary message-handlers found for get-description.
FALSE
CLIPS> (find-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (eq ?f:id ?id-question))
([E1])
CLIPS> (send (nth$ 1 (find-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (eq ?f:id ?id-question))) get-description)
"Choose YES if you don't know ... "
CLIPS> (do-for-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (eq ?f:id ?id-question) ?f:description)
"Choose YES if you don't know ... "
CLIPS> (bind ?id-question "GQ03")
"GQ03"
CLIPS> (send (nth$ 1 (find-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (eq ?f:id ?id-question))) get-description)
[MSGFUN1] No applicable primary message-handlers found for get-description.
FALSE
CLIPS> (do-for-instance ((?f QUESTION)) (eq ?f:id ?id-question) ?f:description)
FALSE
CLIPS>
```